# CSS/Stylish gives HTTP/HTTPS error in background: url()?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, stylish

I got this error:

> The page at 'https://www.google.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure image 'http://i.imgur.com/#####.png'. This
>   content should also be served over HTTPS.

How can I fix this?
My Stylish code:

```css
#hplogo {
    /* these numbers match the new image's dimensions */
    padding-left: 125px !important;
    padding-top: 25px !important;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/cr5pCeF.png) no-repeat !important;
}
```

Comment: Simply change `http` to `https`. This should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser won't complain if you request a "secure" (https) image from an an unsecured (http) page<sup>1</sup>.

So just use `background: url(https://i.imgur.com/cr5pCeF.png) no-repeat !important;`

<sup>1</sup> In your case, Google auto-redirects from http to https anyway, so there won't be a mismatch.

---

Additionally, **for Stylish on Chrome, you can use the auto-protocol form** of the URL.  That is:

```
background: url(//i.imgur.com/cr5pCeF.png) no-repeat !important;
```

But, unfortunately, this is not yet supported in Firefox.  So don't use that in cross-browser Stylish scripts.

Comment: Thank you! Also, can I DELETE images with stylish? (It has to be with <img> tag)

Comment: Since this seems to have answered your question, please [tick the benchmark for this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). .. And, no you cannot delete an image with Stylish, but you can set `display: none !important;`.